# Binding value from QComboBox in QGIS custom Form?

Tags: pyqgis, combo-box

I am trying to build a custom form for field data collection (bird species) with some python logic. The python code inserts values into a QComboBox:

1. At the beginning of the list it adds the twenty most often used species
2. then follows a separator
3. then a complete list of possible species

After finding [Custom QGIS feature forms – Value Binding](http://nathanw.net/2012/03/30/custom-qgis-feature-forms-value-binding/) I learned, that I have to set the correct widget type in the "Fields" tab of the layer properties dialog.

Now QLineEdits (Edit Widget -> "Text Edit") and QSpinBoxes (Edit Widget -> "Range") work as intended. But I can't find a widget type that correctly binds the values of my QComboBoxes.

Which type of "Edit Widget" do I have to choose to bind a QComboBox from a Qt custom form?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems to me, that there is no way to correctly bind a QComboBox. Looks like a bug to me.

I solved the problem by creating a QLineEdit, that is bound to the attribute (set edit widget to "Text Edit"), and hiding this LineEdit behind a ComcoBox. Every change of the value in the ComboBox triggers a function, that sets the text of the LineEdit to the current Text of the ComboBox.

Not elegant, but it works.