# PyQGIS/QGIS2.18 : Store checkbox state as boolean in database (PostGreSQL 9.3)

Tags: pyqgis, postgresql, qgis-2.18, qt-designer

I would like to store the information about whether a checkbox is checked or not in a boolean column in my database (running on PostGreSQL 9.3). I'm using a custom form, and the corresponding checkbox field should appear as checked or unchecked depending on its value in the database - and the value in the database should update if the user changes the state of the checkbox.

I created a variable for the checkbox in my Python script:

```
global zone_humide
zone_humide = dialog.findChild(QCheckBox, "zone_humide")
```

I also made sure that the field has the same name as its corresponding column in the database.
But when I check or uncheck the box, the change is not recorded in the database - and consequently, I can't call back the current state of the box when I open my form again.

Comment: So what's the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up using a workaround by creating a QLineEdit which I associate to my checkbox with a function (same logic as what is described [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/141380/qgis-custom-form-how-to-bind-a-value-from-a-qcombobox?rq=1)). Every time the checkbox is checked, the LineEdit text changes to 't' - otherwise the text is 'f'. It's not very pretty code-wise, but it works and it is not noticeable by the final user. If anyone as a solution that involves less tinkering, I'd be happy to hear about it.

Answer (score 0):

@Mefimefi, just setting the "Edit widget" property as "Check Box" in the layer properties in QGIS works for me.

Comment: I had tried that, using different ways to represent the state (1/0, t/f...), but I couldn't make it work unfortunately.